# How to cleanup CommitLog files using Cassandra in Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, cassandra, hector

I've got a problem that's very similar to the one listed here:

[How to cleanup embedded cassandra after unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944287/how-to-cleanup-embedded-cassandra-after-unittest)

In short, I'm firing up Cassandra to run some integration tests, but when my test classes run they fail as they are unable to delete the CommitLog files that are produced by Cassandra.

I'm following the suggestions in the answer given there, which are to perform cleanup on startup, but at that time the files still cannot be deleted (if I debug through the code, I am also unable to delete the files at that time via the command line or the GUI).  The result is that my first test class passes, but all subsequent ones fail.

Further details:

- My colleagues are running on OSX and do not have this problem; I am on Windows 7.
- I've tried running the tests under DOS and Cygwin, as well as through Eclipse, in all cases both as my local user and as Administrator.
- I've used Process Explorer to confirm that nothing apart from a single Java process has a handle on the file in question.
- I've debugged through the code right down to the native call in java.io.Win32FileSystem, which is unable to delete the file.

Is there anything I can do to ensure Cassandra has shut down and/or deleted its CommitLog file?

Thanks!